# Calculate p-val of new probability vs old probability

Tags: probability, statistics, p-value

I have two distinct probabilities, the old one is p1=0.72 and the new one is p2=0.84.
I have to calculate the p-value of the benefit of the new probability.
How do I calculate this?

Comment: You wrote p-val in the problem. I am thinking that you mean p-value not p-val. You also mentioned two values for a given probability. Is one of them the theoretical value and the other observed value?

Comment: Hi,I corrected my post. You can think of them as two distinct probabilities on the same thing (eg. one tyre type compared to another).What matters is the "check" of the hypothesis that the new probability is better. Obviously you can tell by the probabilities, so I dont really understand what role p-value plays

Comment: You need to provide more information to be able to calculate the p-value. What is the sample size? Or more precisely, how were the probabilities calculated? E.g. provide the number of successes and number of attempts when testing tyres for something.

Comment: That is my exact issue, no sample size or variance is given, no importance value, only the two probabilities

Comment: The exact problem is,given the probabilities of success  of the two different types, calculate the p-value of the new type being more effective

Comment: I see no direct duplicate on this site, perhaps look [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/504837/comparing-two-frequencies/504840#504840) for links beyond my Answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you have two groups 1 and 2. The respective observed success
rates are $\hat p_1 = x_1/n_1$ and $\hat p_2 = x_2/n_2,$
where $x_i$ is the number of successes out of $n_i$ in group $i.$ Then you want to test $H_0: p_1 = p_2$ against
$H_2: p_i \ne p_2$ at the 5% level of significance.
That is, you want a test to compare these two binomial proportions. You can google 'test of binomial proportions' for
various versions of such tests.

One of them is `prop.test` in R statistical software.
If you have $x_1 = 76$ successes out of $n_1 = 200$ trials
in Group 1 and $x_2 = 99$ successes out of $n_2 = 310$ trials in Group 2, then the test gives the results shown below. [I have declined the continuity correction because sample sizes, essentially in the hundreds, are sufficiently large.]

```
prop.test(c(76,99), c(200,310), cor=F)

        2-sample test for equality of proportions 
        without continuity correction

data:  c(76, 99) out of c(200, 310)
X-squared = 1.9837, df = 1, p-value = 0.159
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.02431843  0.14560875
sample estimates:
   prop 1    prop 2 
0.3800000 0.3193548
```

The P-value $0.159 > 0.05 = 5\%$ indicates that
the proportions $\hat p_1 = 0.38$ and $\hat p_2 = 0.32,$
while different, are not *enough* different to be
called significantly different at the 5% level. With samples of this size, one might find sample proportions $\hat p_i$ this
far apart about 16% of the time--even if there is no
real difference between $p_1$ and $p_2.$ A 95% confidence
interval for $p_1 - p_2$ is $(-0.024,  0.146),$ which includes $0.$

This test in R is very nearly the same as a chi-squared test
of the contingency table below, for different proportions of successes.  In the table `TAB` below, rows are for Successes and Failures and Columns are four Groups 1 and 2.

```
suc = c(76, 99);  n = c(200, 310)
fai = n - suc
TAB = rbind(suc,fai);  TAB
    [,1] [,2]
suc   76   99
fai  124  211
```

Then a 'chi-squared test' for a $2 \times 2$ table, in R
gives the output below. If you are not familiar with such
chi-squared tests and if they are not explained in your
statistics text, then you can google that as well.

```
chisq.test(TAB, cor=F)

        Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  TAB
X-squared = 1.9837, df = 1, p-value = 0.159
```

Notice that the P-value is the same as in the test of
binomial proportions shown above. The former may be easier
to understand and the chi-squared test may be more widely
explained in textbooks and online.

*Notes:* (1) As @MarkoLalovic has commented: You really can't compare two binomial proportions without knowing the sample sizes $n_1$ and $n_2.$
If you had exactly the same proportions with three times as many
observations in each group, then those proportions would
be very highly significantly different with a P-value near $0.$

```
prop.test(c(226,249),c(600,930), cor=T)$p.val
[1] 9.02481e-06
```

(2) If there is something in the context of this problem/information that leads you to believe that
there were at least 100 trials in each of the two
groups, then you have a significant difference at level 6% level, for the two proportions you provide:

```
prop.test(c(84, 72),c(100,100), cor=T)$p.val
[1] 0.06042645
```

(3) if the old value $p = 0.72$ is well-established, and you are comparing new proportion $\hat p = 84/100,$ then an exact `binom.test` in R shows strong evidence that the new value is larger:

```
binom.test(84, 100, p=.72, alt="greater") 

    Exact binomial test

data:  84 and 100
number of successes = 84, number of trials = 100, 
 p-value = 0.003671
alternative hypothesis: 
 true probability of success is greater than 0.72
95 percent confidence interval:
  0.7671842 1.0000000
 sample estimates:
 probability of success 
                   0.84
```

Even $\hat p = 42/50 = 0.84$ differs significantly from $0.72$ at the 5% level. [But **not** $\hat p = 21/25.]$

```
binom.test(42, 50, p=.72, alt="greater")$p.val
[1] 0.03645886

binom.test(21, 25, p=.72, alt="greater")$p.val
[1] 0.1303708
```